# Complex Xpath get all values excluding some specific class attributes

Tags: php, html, xml, xpath

I have a markup HTML as below:

```
<body>
    <div>......</div>
    ............
    <div class="entry-content">
        <div class="code1 code2">(ads.....);</div>
        <p><img src="https://www..."></img></p>
        <h2> title </h2>
        <div class="code1-block code2">(ads.....);</div>
        <div class="data1 dta-ta1">
              <ul><li><p> text</p></li>
                  <li><span> text2 </span></li>
                  <li><span> text3 </span></li>
                  <div class="codex1 code-block"><span>(ads ....); </span></div>
                  <li><span> text4 </span></li>
                  <div class="codex1 code-block"><span>(ads ....); </span></div>
              </ul>
        </div> 
        <div class="codex2-block code2">(ads.....);</div>
        <div class="data2-entry dta-ta2">
              <p>
                <span> text5</span>
              </p>
              <p> text6 </p>
              <p> text7 </p
              <div class="codex1 code-block"><span>(ads ....); </span></div>
              <li><span> text8 </span></li>
              <div class="codex1 code-block"><span>(ads ....); </span></div>
        </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I've tried to "go into div with `class="entry-content"` get all texts from its child nodes excluding child nodes with `class= "code1", "code2", "codex1", "codex2"`

My code as below just goes to the div and gets all texts from child nodes. However, I can not remove text from the child nodes with code1 & code2. I appreciate for your supports. Thanks.

```
 $classname='entry-content';
 $a = new DOMXPath($dom);
 $query = "//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]";

 $list = $a->query($query);

 if ($list->length > 0) {
    foreach ($list as $element) {
        $nodes = $element->childNodes;

          foreach ($element as $node) {
             $bodytext = trim(preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', ' ', $node->nodeValue));
             $bodyContent .= '<p>' . $bodytext . '</p>';
          }
    }
 }
```

My expected output:

https://www...

title

text2

text3

text4

text5

text6

text7

text8

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I want to get all texts from child nodes insde div with class="content" and exclude child nodes with class contain "code" EX:code1 code2, codex1, codex2.... it's a bit challenge because of the complex HTML markup. I think we need a complex queries xpath.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the expected output *for the sample input you have provided*

Comment: ok ! I've just edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input document is not well-formed, a `>` is missing for `</p`, and one `div` is not closed properly. With the input document fixed, a working path expression is

**XPath expression**

```
//div[@class='content']//text()[not(ancestor::div/@class[contains(., 'code')])][normalize-space()]
```

It selects all text nodes, but only if they do not have an ancestor `div` element that has a `class` attribute whose value contains "code", and also, the text nodes selected cannot be whitespace-only.

**Output**

Individual results are separated by `------`:

```
 title 
-----------------------
 text
-----------------------
 text2 
-----------------------
 text3 
-----------------------
 text4 
-----------------------
 text5
-----------------------
 text6 
-----------------------
 text7 
-----------------------
 text8
```

**Update**

> I tried with your answer. It works however I still need a source from img tag. How can I get it?

It's possible to also select the `source` attribute of an `img` element, but this would make the Xpath expression even more complicated. You should just add another line of PHP to evaluate a separate path expression, such as:

```
//div[@class='entry-content']/p/img/@source
```

**Update 2**

While I absolutely do not recommend to use this expression (because it obfuscates your code), here is how to combine both expressions into a single one with a union operator:

```
//div[@class='entry-content']//text()[not(ancestor::div/@class[contains(., 'code')])][normalize-space()] | //div[@class='entry-content']//p/img/@src
```

Comment: Thanks, Mathias, for your answer. I fixed with a closed /div. I tried with your answer. It works however I still need a source from img tag. How can I get it?

Comment: @AnNguyen I've updated my answer to address your question.

Comment: It's great if it can be combined in one. Your modified answer works perfectly. I also tested another way to get the source `$tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('img'); 
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $featureImage = $tag->getAttribute('src');
}`. Then it works as well. Thanks, Mathias.  I appreciate if you can combine it in one line only! Voted up your answer.

Comment: @AnNguyen Updated my answer again. Please note that you should probably not use this expression since it's too complex. Evaluating two expressions in your PHP code makes more sense.

Comment: Yeah you're right. It took a searching result longer than separating part. I tried to use your new code for img source but it's not success. It returns null value.    `$img_query = "//div[@class='entry-content']//p/img/@src";
$imglist = $a->query($img_query);
foreach ($imglist as $imgitem) { 
$featureImage=$imgitem->nodeValue;
}` . I'm not sure with my code to extract attribute src